# libetpan15 not installable when trying to install Cairo dock

Tags: dependencies

When adding Cairo dock to Ubuntu 12.04, i get this message telling me i need a dependency. What do i do now to proceed with the install?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cairo-dock-plug-ins : Depends: libetpan15 (>= 1.0) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/1419516/

Comment: Never mind, done it now. http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies